# View windows filename stored under Linux

Tags: linux, windows, character-encoding, filenames, samba

I've got a Linux box with a Samba server on it.
So, I'm storing from Windows computers some files, with special latin characters.

My problem, is that non ASCII is not correctly displayed with a ls command from the Linux box.
For example:

```
# ls
Ã©trangÃ¨re.txt
```

My LANG env variable is set to en_GB.UTF-8.

I tries several mount isocharset options (iso8859-1, iso8859-15, utf8...), but always the same problem.

So do you know how to list correctly Windows filename type in a linux world?

Thanks in advance,
Raoul.

Comment: What encoding does your terminal use?

Answer (score 0):

As Karol point out, my terminal encoding was set to ISO-8859-1, but my server uses UTF-8.

After setting my terminal encoding to UTF-8, I can correctly see non ASCII characters.

Thanks Karol.